# Haskell print a return value (Yet Another Haskell Tutorial, askForWords)

Tags: haskell, printing, compiled

So I'm trying to print out a line of text to the terminal window using a returned value in a compiled code. The program looks like this:

```haskell
module Main
    where

import System.IO

main = do
  askForWords

askForWords = do
  putStrLn "Pleas enter a word:"
  word <- getLine
  if word == ""
    then return []
    else do
      rest <- askForWords
      return (word ++ " " ++ rest)
```

When I run it in the GHCi it works fine

```
*Main> main 
Pleas enter a word:
Hello
Pleas enter a word:
World
Pleas enter a word:

"Hello World "
*Main>
```

When I try to run the Unix executable file the program don't print the last string

```
% /Users/tobyone/Workspace/Haskell/yaht/Yaht ; exit;
Pleas enter a word:
Hello
Pleas enter a word:
World
Pleas enter a word:


[Process completed]
```

I have tried printing out `askForWords` in main with `putStrLn` but get the error

```
<interactive>:2:10: error:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO [Char]’ with ‘[Char]’
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: How did you try to use `putStrLn`? It seems you did that wrong, but if you don't show your mistake we can't tell how to correct it.

Comment: GHCi performs some magic. When you write `1+2`, it actualy runs `print (1+2)`. When you write `return (1+2)` it actually runs `do it <- return (1+2) ; print it`. In your code, you run `askForWords` in your `main`, but silently discard its result. GHCi would have converted that to `do it <- askForWords ; print it`, but in a program you have to be explicit about that (and possibly use `putStrLn` instead of `print`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't printing the output, you are only returning it. Your executable effectively ignores the return value of the `main`, which conventionally has type `IO ()` to emphasize this.

```
module Main
    where

import System.IO

main = do
  result <- askForWords
  putStrLn result

askForWords = do
  putStrLn "Pleas enter a word:"
  word <- getLine
  if word == ""
    then return []
    else do
      rest <- askForWords
      return (word ++ " " ++ rest)
```

In GHCi (like REPLs in most languages), the value of an expression is printed to the terminal.

`main` could also be defined more simply as

```
main = askForWords >>= putStrLn
```